# ios data storage and webservice query best practices?

Tags: ios, json, sqlite, http, core-data

I am developing an app that fetches and pushes data to a web service and I would like to know How to do it **right**

My app lets the user create a "group" and add his/her friends to this group where everyone would participate in this group

My initial design got me with these Data Models

Group,
Member,
Contribution

I am thinking about using a java web backend with JSON to serialize the data before sending.

Now Here are my questions:

1-What is the best way to store my models locally on the client? is it Core Data?

2- I don`t wanna fetch the group and contributions data every time the user tries to view them, so I am thinking about adding a property to the group called groupSerial which will be increased with every change , In this way the client app will query the server for the serial and fetch the group if it is different from its local version
Is this a good idea and the best way to do it? if not what is?

3- I would like to fetch the data using HTTPS requests (GET for fetching and POST for updating) , Is this the best way to do it? any best practices to consider?

4- Is it a good idea to sub class the core data entity class and add utility methods to do relative work that involves the super class

For example I would have a core data entity class called Group , so I would make a sub class called XYZGroup that would have the following class methods

```
+(Group)fetchGroup:(NSString gid); // return the latest version of the group ,whether from local storage or the web server 
+(void)newGroup:(Group)group; //push the new group to the web server and update local data
+(NSArray)getGroupsSummaries;//Return an array of meta data about joined groups
```

Also , I would have a class called XYZMember  that would have some methods like:

```
+(NSString)myMemberID;
+(NSArray)getMembers:(NSArray)numbersInContacts;//Takes a list of phone numbers and returns an array of members that have the app installed
```

5-Do I need additional entity classes to store the data locally , for example: Do I need a core data entity class called Mygroups that would have an array of the groups the user is currently in

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1, if you want to store lightweight data only, json is better than core data.
2, it depends what you implement web service and what you want to export
3, you can use WSDL xml file and use WSDLParser.app to generate obj-c code.
4, up to you
5, up to you